# html 5 validation is not working on jQuery-steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-steps

**I have 4 Step**

[image: I have 4 step]

**i put validation on first_name like below.**

```
 <label for="firstname" id="firstname">First Name</label>
 <input type="text" id="firstname" name="il_first_name" required>
```

**Final Step**

[image: final step]
**at the end on click submit using j query-steps i want to check html 5 validators to check validation of entire form (step 1 to last step)**

Comment: it wont work because at the time of finish button its given as hidden element,

Comment: I don't get your problem. can you ask a question?
but at first, you are using a unique ID twice in your little code example.
and then it might be good to validate each step when click continue button // i guess there is a continue or next step button below you form.

Answer (score 0):

it wont work because at the time of finish button its given as hidden element

try doing it at each step in the form

or else try this `required = "required"`
also change your same id name for label and input